# boost::any_cast throw with program options c++

Tags: c++, boost

I have the following code;

```
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::program_options;
using namespace boost::filesystem;
using namespace cv;

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;


int     frames2skip;

options_description desc("Allowed options");
desc.add_options();

("frames2skip", value<int>(&frames2skip)->default_value(2));

variables_map opts;
store(parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), opts);

frames2skip = opts["frames2skip"].as<int>();
```

I get the following error after after assigning `'frames2skip'` at last line:

```
what():  boost::bad_any_cast: failed conversion using boost::any_cast 
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What is wrong and how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
desc.add_options();
               // ^ rogue semicolon, the next line is a separate statement made up
               // of parenthesized comma-expression and has no effect on `desc`.
("frames2skip", value<int>(&frames2skip)->default_value(2));
```

Comment: Yuri, could you more briefly explain what do you mean?

Comment: @yusuf what exactly is unclear? Remove the indicated semicolon to fix your thing.